Tearjerker Film where man returns home years later and is not recognized
I saw this movie (U.S.) one afternoon on TV around 1965 when I was home sick.  Major tearjerker.  The movie ends with a man, who everyone believes has been dead for several years, walking back to his home in the cold (I believe its Christmas time) and his wife answers the door but doesn't recognize him.  They talk and she invites him in, out of pity I think, and he says no.  He then walks away in the cold.  This ending resulted in my babysitter (and myself) sobbing.
In an earlier scene someone attempts to kill him near some train tracks but he successfully defends himself.  For some reason this event forces him to disappear for a while.
Most likely a U.S. film, saw it in the late fall in the afternoon. Afternoon movies were usually showing films that were 3 to 10 years old (i.e. movie from late 50's early 60's).
That's all I can remember but if anyone knows which film this is then I would be forever grateful.

Could it be Tomorrow is Forever?  
From Wikipedia:  

The movie tells the story of Elizabeth (Colbert) and John (Welles), a married couple recently separated when John goes off to fight in World War I. When Elizabeth receives notice of John's death, she marries another man (George Brent). John, however, is still alive, and later returns, but after being disfigured in the war he has undergone plastic surgery, making him almost unrecognizable. He has also adopted an eight-year old daughter (Wood). When he finds out that he has a son with Elizabeth, he is faced with the dilemma of whether or not to reveal his true identity.

I'm not sure if it's the one, but it has similarities although I couldn't find anything about those train and door scenes.  
Notable additions: it's a film made in USA and the time of release is 1946.

This might just be it. The fact that he has grown a beard (according to one review) makes sense with what I remember.  I will watch it to make sure and will provide an update.  Thank-you

Having just watched "Tomorrow is Forever", I am 80-90% convinced that this is the film.  The look of the character John, played by Orson Wells, with the beard and the long black coat matches my memory exactly.  There are a few other similarities such as John never revealing the truth and of course the very sad ending.  I guess having watched this about 50 years ago (being 5 or 6 years old) my memory of some of the other scenes are simply false.  Thank you.

@ErnieT. I'm glad to hear it :)
